# Tomcat issue trying to force browser to display customer error handle webpage?

Tags: java, xml, servlets

just had a question. Does anyone know how to force tomcat to use customer web pages dynamically created by servlets when implementing error handling ?

My code is on my github site. I listed it as public, so anyone can see the code. It is also based on a training course provided at the following site. It is a few years old, but I think it should still work.

https://www.journaldev.com/1973/servlet-exception-and-error-handling-example-tutorial

My site details :

https://github.com/K3123/compreport/tree/master/ServletExceptionHandlingTest
`

```
package com.journaldev.servlet.exception;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/AppExceptionHandler")
public class AppExceptionHandler extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processError(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processError(request, response);
}

private void processError(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    // Analyze the servlet exception
    Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request
            .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
    Integer statusCode = (Integer) request
            .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
    String servletName = (String) request
            .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.servlet_name");
    if (servletName == null) {
        servletName = "Unknown";
    }
    String requestUri = (String) request
            .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");
    if (requestUri == null) {
        requestUri = "Unknown";
    }

    // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.write("<html><head><title>Exception/Error Details</title></head><body>");
      if(statusCode != 500){
          out.write("<h3>Error Details</h3>");
          out.write("<strong>Status Code</strong>:"+statusCode+"<br>");
          out.write("<strong>Requested URI</strong>:"+requestUri);
      }else{
          out.write("<h3>Exception Details</h3>");
          out.write("<ul><li>Servlet Name:"+servletName+"</li>");
          out.write("<li>Exception Name:"+throwable.getClass().getName()+"</li>");
          out.write("<li>Requested URI:"+requestUri+"</li>");
          out.write("<li>Exception Message:"+throwable.getMessage()+"</li>");
          out.write("</ul>");
      }

      out.write("<br><br>");
      out.write("<a href=\"index.html\">Home Page</a>");
      out.write("</body></html>");
  }
}
```

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>ServletExceptionHandling</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
 <error-code>404</error-code>
 <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
<exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
<location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Hello Everyone,

Comment: Ok, so the following code worked to resolve the issue with Tomcat. However, I'm not sure why it doesn't work with the original code. Can anyone help me to understand why the updated code works verses the original code?

Comment: What URL you are testing?

Comment: I used the journaldev.com site as a template to create a error handling servlet. I was able to get it to work, but it required adding a blank page in the out.println before the main error handle page would be displayed. It works, but doesn't work correctly. I shouldn't require the creation of a false page to get the real page to appear. The journaldev.com site provides the tutorial and code that should work. However, it didn't work for me and I had to create an alternative to get it to work. My code is provided on GitHub.